# How to insert conditional statement or IF ELSE FUNCTION on SELECT QUERY

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Ex:
I need to find out if their are "milligrams" at my column, which is the prod_unit. If so, I'll change it to "grams".

I try this query :

```
Select concat (`prod_name`,' - ',`prod_quantity`,' ',`prod_unit`) 
from prod_table;
```

I need to get this Ex:

```
Soy Sauce - 800 milligrams
```

Becomes:

```
Soy Sauce - 800 grams
```

Good luck guys. I need your help pleassseee.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CONCAT(prod_name,'-',prod_quantity,' ',
    CASE WHEN prod_unit = 'milligrams' THEN 'grams' 
         ELSE prod_unit 
    END) AS shortName 
FROM prod_table;
```